# is it possible to save a reactive form in a service and instantiate it in multiple component?

Tags: angular, forms

I m using the same reactive form in multiple components, I would like to avoid code duplication and "store" my reactive form in a service in order to instantiate it in my component when I need it. Can someone tell me if it is possible with angular?

Perhaps there is a better other way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You could have try it to figure it out.

You can think of your service as a factory for the form.

EDIT:
Most of the time, I do encapsulate reactiv form into a service. Even if it is used only once.

I think it is a good practice to do so as it splits the responsibilities into different classes.

It makes it way easier to test as the service’s responsibilities are then limited to the form only (and not the whole component).
More over, you will be able to mock the behaviour of the form into the component’s tests.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22157468)

Comment: I did answer to his question.

Comment: Hello Grégory, thanks for your answer. I could have try it but even if it works, I want to know it is a good practice